# postgresql 9.2 never vacuumed and analyze

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have given a postgres 9.2 DB around 20GB of size.

I looked through the database and saw that it has been never run vacuum and/or analyze on any tables. 
Autovacuum is on and the transaction wraparound limit is very far (only 1% of it).

I know nothing about the data activity (number of deletes,inserts, updates), but I see, it uses a lot of index and sequence.
My question is:

1. does the lack of vacuum and/or analyze affect data integrity (for example a select doesn't show all the rows matches the select from a table or from an index)? The speed of querys and writes doesn't matter.
2. is it possible that after the vacuum and/or analyze the same query gives a different answer than it would executed before the vacuum/analyze command?

I'm fairly new to PG, thank you for your help!!

Regards,
Figaro88

Comment: 1): not, 2): no (unless there are unknown bugs in Postgres)

Comment: After a `VACUUM` a query without `ORDER BY something` can return rows in different order.

Comment: What method are you using to determine it has never been vacuumed or analyzed?

Comment: I used the following command:
SELECT schemaname, relname, last_autoanalyze, last_analyze, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum FROM pg_stat_all_tables ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running vacuum and/or analyze will not change the result set produced by any select operation (unless there was a bug in PostgreSQL). They may effect the order of results if you do not supply an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: What is the consequence of rare/never vacuum and/or analyze other than slow queries?

For example adding a new column to a formerly analyzed table and inserting a great number of new rows but don't analyze it makes the new columns data unselectable or just the queries matches these rows would be slower?

Comment: Since 8.1, unless you specifically turn it off, PostgreSQL will automatically vacuum (which also analyzes) your databases. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/maintenance.html

Comment: It could make many queries slower, not just ones matching those rows.

Comment: The autovacuum is on, so it's not a problem. 

I just afraid that the un-analyzed tables give wrong result sets to queries (not show all matching rows). Really hope dead rows can't be selected or updated.
Sorry for lame questions, but I cannot find clear answers in the documentactions about the lack and consequences of no vacuum and no analyze.